# In MVC, How can i navigate data through model object in View dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get person details based on id through Model only.
I have create a ModelView class in which i have person detail's properties and a method, GetList which is returning list object of all persons data.

Once i got that list data passed from controller to View, I now want to show person's data based on the Id entered in textbox and appear the rest of the details in other textboxes on tab out of first textBox.

For this i don't want to go to controller again because i have all the data on View, so how do i filter data on View only.

Could anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: The controller should do all the heavy lifting. Send info from the view to the controller, from the controller to the model, from the model back to the controller, and finally, from the controller to the view.

Comment: That's what i am doing right now, but i don't want to go back to controller, once i have all the data on view,  I just want to implement some functionality on view, so that i can filter data on  view itself based on id. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you have and more specifically explain the issue you are having with the code?

Comment: You don't seem to understand how asp.net MVC works.  It's *impossible" to "go back to the controller" once you're in the view.  So that route can't happen (barring `Html.Action` helpers or ajax updates, which is really a different thing).  You pass all data to the view that the view needs, which means populating your model with all the data prior to returning the model to the view.  You don't do any logic in your view, so there is no reason to "go back" even if you could.

Comment: I want to implement a requirement in MVC where i have one textbox and 4 labels, User will enter personId in textBox and on tab out of that textbox i want to fill all the 4 labels with the correspond data against that id. I implemented httpget action in controller and get the data back. What i want, instead of going for each paersonId to controller's action, can i get all data in one request on View and fetch it as per personId each time on view?

Comment: The answer to your question will require Javascript/Jquery. Although sending a complete list of data to your view can be time consuming. If you are satisfied with including Javascript on your view, I can give you an example that would head you in the right direction

Comment: Also @tlindell - That is incorrect. Your controller should NOT do all the heavy lifting

Comment: Abdul--Please let me know the example you are talking about, I want to implement something like MV-VM
--Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AbdulG You are correct! The controller should not do all the heavy lifting. I actually found that out recently and know now that the work should actually be done in the model. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @AnmolBali Apologies for this late response. Haven't been back here in a while. Has your question been answered? Would you still like my assistance?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use following approach :

1. you fill all users data in controller with respect to userid.
2. in your view at first you just display empty userid text box.
3. after enter userid value in text box you can write change event of
   that text box by jquery as :

   ```
   $('#IdOfTextBox').change(function(){ 
     //write your hide and show and data filling logic here
   });
   ```

Comment: But how would i write model's logic in jquery event in view?

Comment: Hi All, I found the answer, I can do this by building JavaScript MVVM apps in MVC using KnockoutJS. It sounds great.